# adding objects to ArrayList using BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

I am working on my own project using BlueJ, which we use as the main IDE in my course currently.

This is more of a question and not sure how to phrase it.

```
public class Test
{

    public Test()
    {

    }

}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class Add
{
    ArrayList<Test> nTest;

    public Add()
    {
         nTest = new ArrayList<Test>();
    }

    public void addTest(Test test)
    {
        nTest.add(new Test());
    }
}
```

While compiling, there are no errors. Yet When I make new Add, and call the method, I get the following window which I have no idea what to do with.

Screenshot of the problem

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bluej, but I think you need to have a `Test()` object in that drop down to pass into the `addTest()` method. The "Java-speak" for this would be instatiate a new Test object before the addTest() call and then pass the Test object in as a parameter. You're not actually using the parameter though inside of the `addTest()` method, and could probably just remove that parameter requirement

Comment: It should be `nTest.add(test)` or `public void addTest()`

Comment: You should be asking your instructor.  As a guess I'd say since you don't have a main method BlueJ is making one for you and suggesting a statement to invoke your `addTest()` method.  But that's just a guess based on what you have posted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I use BlueJ in my course too.
Create your "Test" object first and let BlueJ define the name (probably "test 1"). Then, you can create an "Add" object like you've already done in your example.

To use your add method, you need to right-click on the "Add" object and select the "addTest" method. Select the "test 1" object and validate. You added an object Test called "test 1" to your ArrayList.

You haven't got any method to give you a trace so you can inspect the "Add" object twice to see what's happen when you add an object in your list.